# Why is the following (supposedly) forming a recursive call in a single process?

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, recursion

A bit of background information before I insert the code:
I was given the task of writing a program that finds the min, max and sum from an array. The way the task dictates to have this accomplished is through the use of a process chain, having one process spawn a child, which that child spawns another child, etc. - each taking a chunk of the array to process.
I am not using any type of exec, since I need communication throughout the entire procedure - the grandest child will report back its own parent, which will then proceed to report to its parent, so on and so forth.
The issue I am having is that on the second child, a method I created (called worker) seems to be performed twice, recursively. The second child is going through its own data first, but then proceeds to recurse and go through the data of the first child.

Here is the code of the method called worker:

```
void worker(int start, int num, long * cur, FILE * fso, int pipefd[]){
    /*
     * start is the starting index for cur - the array of longs
     * num is the number of processes to still be created
     */

    close(pipefd[0]); // close reading portion of initial pipe - communicates to parent from this child

    int pid = -2;

    int * pipefd2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2); // second pipe to talk with the child about to be spawned

    if(num > 0){
        if(pipe(pipefd2) == -1)
            handle_error("pipe");
        pid = fork();
    }

    if(pid == 0)
        worker(start + 5, num-1, cur, fso, pipefd2);
    else if(pid == -1)
        handle_error("fork");

    /*
     * Start of finding local information
     */

    long sum, min, max;

    sum = cur[start];
    min = sum;
    max = min;

    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        sum += cur[start+i];
        if(max < cur[start+i])
            max = cur[start+i];
        else if (min > cur[start+i])
            min = cur[start+i];
    }

    /*
     * Found the local sum, max and min - now to acquire the sum, max and min from the child (if applicable)
     */

    close(pipefd2[1]); // dont need writing portion to hear from child

    if(pid != -2){ // checking if child was spawned, and now to deal with it
        long buf; // buffer to hold incoming longs

        i = read(pipefd[0], &buf, sizeof(long)); // j is an error catch - read will first read the sum found
        if(i == -1)
            handle_error("read01");
        sum += buf;

        i = read(pipefd[0], &buf, sizeof(long)); // then it reads the min found
        if(i == -1)
            handle_error("read02");
        if(buf < min)
            min = buf;

        i = read(pipefd[0], &buf, sizeof(long)); // and finally the max that was found is read
        if(i == -1)
            handle_error("read03");
        if(max < buf)
            max = buf;
    }

    close(pipefd2[0]);

    wait(NULL);

    int err;
    err = fprintf(fso, "Hi I'm process %d and my parent is %d.\n", (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());

    if(err < 0)
        handle_error_en(5, "fprintf failed unexpectedly");

    err = write(pipefd[1], &sum, sizeof(long));
    if(err == -1)
        handle_error("write");

    err = write(pipefd[1], &min, sizeof(long));
    if(err == -1)
        handle_error("write");

    err = write(pipefd[1], &max, sizeof(long));
    if(err == -1)
        handle_error("write");

    close(pipefd[1]);
    return;
}
```

Things to note: I made each chunk from the array 5 'longs'. I do get a pipe error, but I am assuming this is due to the fact that a true pipping hasn't been made with the recursively called method.

Comment: After the child calls `worker()` recursively it falls through to the rest of the code. So both the parent and child execute that code.

Comment: What is `pipefd2` for, and why do you allocate it with `malloc()` instead of just declaring a local array? You also never `free(pipefd2);`

Comment: It is supposed to go to the rest of that code - the issue lies that the child should not call `worker()` more than once, and I'm not sure why it does. As for pipefd2 being malloced, I wasn't sure that a local array would work. However, I am not concerned about memory leaks at the moment. And the reason pipefd2 exists is to allow communication between the child and the grandchild.

Comment: What makes you say that the child is calling `worker()` twice? The problem I see is that the parent and child are processing the same chunk of the array when `worker()` returns.

Comment: You never use `pipefd2` for communication between the child and grandchild. Maybe you meant to pass `pipefd2` in the call to `worker()`?

Comment: Ah yes, that is indeed an error - concerning pipefd2. As for why I say that the child is calling `worker()` twice is because as I was debugging the code in Eclipse CDT, I saw `worker()` twice under the third process (second child) and `worker()` thrice under the fourth process (third child).

Comment: Make sure you have output buffering turned off in `fso`. Otherwise the buffer will be duplicated when you `fork()`.

Comment: Ah well, speaking of fso - I edited the code as per your notice of the bug concerning pipefd2, and everything is being written the the output file correctly. There is proper communication between the parent and its children/grandchildren. However, I am still getting a read error - occurring at the first read (labeled read01). Running the code through eclipse, I still see `worker()` being called twice under the second child - so that is still an issue.

And thank you for that catch of pipefd2.

Comment: Since you're using a debugger, you should be able to single-step through the program, and see how it's getting there in each process.

Comment: That is the curious thing, I have been stepping through the program and yet it still eludes me.

Comment: How are you calling `worker()` from the main program? Could there be a loop there?

Comment: I have just found out that I am blind (jokingly). The reason that I saw two `worker()` methods under one child is due to the fact that the child is spawned in `worker()` and then proceeds to create its own version of `worker()`. I presume this is what you were alluding to earlier, and I did not understand what you meant. My apologies. I do indeed call `worker()` from the main method, but there is no loop. I now know where to look for errors, so I thank you for lending me your eyes on this code.

Comment: The other issue that I saw is that I `close(pipefd[0])` and then proceed to try to read from that pipe later on.